# Let $H$ be an order 9 group generated by 2 elements $a,b$ that commute and have at most order 3.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $H$ be a group with identity $1_H$ that is generated by 2 elements $a,b$ that commute ($ab=ba$) and where each has at most order $3$. In symbols (I hope I translated correctly):

$$H=\langle a,b\rangle \ \text{, where} \ a^3=b^3=1_H=a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$$

Assuming $H$ has exactly order 9 and assuming $\{a,b,1_H\}$ are all distinct, **what is $H$ isomorphic to?** ([order 9 possibilities](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_9) are $\mathbb Z_9$ and $\mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_3$)

---

**For order 9**: Assuming $H$ is of order 9, I believe $H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_3$.

Construct a map $\gamma: \mathbb Z_3^2 \to H$, $\gamma(c \times d)=b^ca^d$, where $c,d \in \{0,1,2\}$.

Show $\gamma$ is bijective: obvious

Show $\gamma$ is a homomorphism: For each $c,d,e,f \in \{0,1,2\}$, we must show that

(**notation**: instead of $(c,d) \in \mathbb Z_3^2$, I'll say $c \times d$)

$$\gamma(c \times d + e \times f) = \gamma(c \times d) \gamma(e \times f)$$

I believe this is equivalent to

$$b^{c+d}a^{e+f} = b^ca^d b^ea^f$$

Finally, because $a^db^e=b^ea^d$ for $d,e \in \{0,1,2\}$, we have that

$$RHS = b^ca^d b^ea^f = b^cb^e a^da^f = LHS$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to go back that far.

The possibilities of $H$ is $\mu_9$ or $\mu_3\times\mu_3$. The former has an element of order 9(the generator), and the latter has no element of order 9.

Every element of $H$ is looks like this: $a^mb^n$, and it has order 3 or less, so it can't be order 9(because $(a^mb^n)^3=a^mb^na^mb^na^mb^n=a^{3m}b^{3n}=(a^3)^m(b^3)^n=1_H^m1_H^n=1_H$.)

So $H\cong\mu_3\times\mu_3$ .

Comment: thanks Nightflight. i am so dumb/forgetful though. i meant to ask about like if we don't use classification. of course classification then we just do your way. without using classification is my isomorphism correct?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon Yes, your isomorphism is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Notation: Elements of $X\times Y$ are generally written as ordered pairs $(x,y)$, not $x\times y$. Also, avoid using $e$ and an element, as its usually reserved for additive identities.

To be clear, we are looking at $\varphi:(\mathbb Z_3\times \mathbb Z_3,+)\to (H,\cdot)$ defined by $\varphi((c,d))=b^c\cdot a^d$. Therefore,

\begin{align*}
\varphi((x,y)+(z,w))&=\varphi((x+z,y+w))\\
&=b^{x+z}\cdot a^{y+w}\\
&=b^x\cdot b^z\cdot a^y\cdot a^w\\
&=(b^x\cdot a^y)\cdot (b^z\cdot a^w)\\
&=\varphi((x,y))\cdot\varphi((z,w)),
\end{align*}

so it is indeed a homomorphism.

Comment: Bonnaduck thanks but i can't help but laugh at the error of '$=\varphi((x+z,y+w)$' now do you see why i use $\times$? haha

Comment: Indeed, fixed! Still, I would recommend getting off that notation. $\times$ is reserved for other operations, and, as you saw in the comments, it leads to confusion.

Comment: But then again some books will use $a \times b$ because of the confusion with intervals. then again other books will say $]a,b[$ instead of $(a,b)$. so which is better: $(a,b)$ for intervals and $a \times b$ for points or $(a,b)$ for points and $]a, b[$ for intervals? (or maybe $a \times b$ for points and $]a,b[$ for intervals ?)

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon Context matters, obviously, and it is true that some students may get confused between points and interval notation. I personally have never seen a textbook or paper use $a\times b$ to represent elements in a direct product, but if this is how your textbook/class is using it, I concede that you should continue as well.

Comment: Bonnaduck, thanks. that's not how it's done in my textbook/class hehe, but it is technically done in some books right? i can't really recall any right now though.